FPGA->PC data transmission over commodity networking hardware
We have a set of physical hardware that comprises a collection of up to 8 modules, each of which is a SoC combining an FPGA and an ARM core running Linux. Currently, all of these modules are connected to a single PC over ethernet, and on the module, all the communication is handled using the normal TCP/IP stack in Linux, with data from the FPGA being routed through the software layer.
This system works well and is reliable, and having the system use normal networking protocols and standards has proven to have real benefits. The problem with the current system is that we are producing data from the FPGA at a much higher data rate than can be handled by the processor (both because the processor is not fast enough, and because the ethernet hardware is 1Gb/s).
We are proposing to have a second data stream from the FPGA which is passed over a dedicated SFP+ optical link. Obviously, there are many ways in which this could be implemented.  Our current thinking is, at the FPGA level, we simply pack the data in ethernet frames and fire it out over the optical link at 10Gb/s. Each module's optical link is then plugged into one of the 8 lanes available on a dual QSFP+ commodity networking card.
Flow control is then handled over the existing software TCP link at the application layer. I.e. only sending any data if the QSFP+ NIC has sufficient space in its buffers.
We can detect loss of data, but we would hope this would happen vanishingly rarely.
The question then is what the pitfalls of such an architecture might be.
Are ethernet frames passed one-per-link in the case of QSFP+ (i.e. each frame is not striped across the 4 links), so each of the 4 QSFP+ links can be driven from a different module?
Can I easily receive the raw ethernet frames on the receiving side, under either Linux or Windows?
Is using flow control based on buffer space good enough to reliably not lose packets (assuming the architecture described)?
Are certain bits/manufacturers of kit better for this kind of thing?

Note that host implementations and issues are explicitly off topic here.

Are ethernet frames passed one-per-link in the case of QSFP+ (i.e. each frame is not striped across the 4 links), so each of the 4 QSFP+ links can be driven from a different module?

With a 40G link, data is split/striped across all four lanes. Many 40G ports support splitting into four 10G links (using a breakout cable), which behave like separate ports mostly.
Ethernet frames may be sent back-to-back, with the next start-frame delimiter following right after the 12-octet inter-packet gap.

Can I easily receive the raw ethernet frames on the receiving side, under either Linux or Windows?

Off topic here. For programming, you might want to try on Stack Overflow. Generally, I'd seriously recommend using the IP stack for communication, ie. TCP or UDP.

Is using flow control based on buffer space good enough to reliably not lose packets (assuming the architecture described)?

Depends on the host hardware and implementation, off topic here.

Are certain bits/manufacturers of kit better for this kind of thing?

We cannot recommend any products here, in general.

Thanks for the reply. I'm a bit puzzled by your assertion various things are off topic. Are these not networking engineering questions? The help page doesn't specify that software related questions are off topic. Perhaps you can clarify what is on topic?

Please see the [help/on-topic] for what our community has decided is on topic here. Installation, configuration, or use of applications not generally considered to be tools used by network professionals, as well as configuration or operation of hosts/servers/VMs are explicitly off topic.

Your question is essentially 'how do I use commodity network hardware to do a not-network solution?' so it is inherently off topic in a networking-focused group like this. If you want an easy answer to your issue, simply use the QSFP+ interfaces and a faster processor and/or use the TCP offload features of the network interface cards to lower the load on your processor that you already use. Any modern hardware should be able to make good use of 40 gigabit (or 25 at least) network links but to do so via TCP  you need multiple streams. UDP might be able to do so more effectively in a single one.
